# Moving files to a new folder inside their parent based on a criteria

Tags: powershell, file-management

I am currently working on a project in Powershell, which I am really not super familiar with. I have gotten pretty close, and done some looking around to get me even closer, but I am stumped on this bigtime.

The goal is to recursively search a directory for files prepended with "`\_7Y_`" (this was done by another script I wrote, based on the files age) and to create a new subdirectory in that files parent and then to move it there. For example, if I have `~\desktop\old\\_7Y_OldFile.txt`, I want that file to go to `~\desktop\old\\_7Y_\\_7Y_OldFile.txt` and I want it to do that for every file recursively.

My script currently creates the folders as expected, but selects only one of the new folders to move the item to. I think this is due to the $child variable selecting only that one value, as after it moves the file the script continues but gets errors trying to find the files to move them. Short of manually telling it each parent (this process will eventually be automated), I was wondering what could be done to make a distinction between each $child for the move.

It is also my understanding that I shouldn't need to do a New-Item and then the Move-Item, as long as I use - force, but that has not been my experience either. Any help would be appreciated.

I apologize for the strange formatting and techniques -- I've really been learning powershell by ear as I go.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'any'})]
[string] $InputFilePath
)
#this sets the filepath parameter to mandatory, so you will need to input 
your own filepath!

$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $InputFilePath -recurse | Measure-Object 
$7Yno = Get-ChildItem $InputFilePath -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '_7Y_*.*'} | Measure-Object
#These are used as the conditions for the if statements
#directoryInfo gets the number of files in the directory; 7Yno gets the number of files prepended with _7Y_ in the directory

$Confirmation = Read-Host "Are you SURE you want to proceed with this operation? All selected files in the given directory will be moved to new directories! This action is irreversable. Your selected directory is $InputFilePath. Enter 'Yes' to proceed"

if ($Confirmation -eq "Yes") {

    if ($directoryInfo.count -gt 0 -and $7Yno.count -gt 0){   #Check: Files in directory and files prepended with _7Y_ in directory.

    $children = @((Get-ChildItem $InputFilePath -recurse | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -like "_7Y_*.*"}).directory.fullname | 
            Get-Unique)
    $Files = @(Get-ChildItem $children -recurse | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -like "_7Y_*.*"})

        foreach($child in $children){
            $7yPath = "$child\_7Y_"
            New-Item -itemtype Directory -path $7yPath -force
        }
        foreach($file in $Files){
            Move-Item $file.fullname -destination $7yPath -force
        }
    }

    if ($directoryInfo.count -gt 0 -and $7Yno.count -eq 0){   #Check: Files in directory, but no files prepended with _7Y_ in directory.
    Read-Host "There are no files prepended with _7Y_ in this directory!"
    }

    if ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0){                            #Check: No files in directory.
    Read-Host "There are no files in this directory!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are moving files to a subdir that move is of course reversible without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are IMO overcomplicating things.

- Get-ChildItem with prefix recursively
- if parent folder name not equal to prefix

  - check if folder exists, if not create it
  - move file to folder

**EDIT: streamline script with only once using** `"$($_.Directory)\$Prefix"`

```
Push-Location 'X:\Folder\to\start'
$Prefix = '_7Y_'
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter "$Prefix*" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.Directory.Name -ne $Prefix} |
    ForEach-Object {
      $DirPrefix = "$($_.Directory)\$Prefix"
      If(!(Test-Path $DirPrefix)){
        Md $DirPrefix | Out-Null
      }
      $_ | Move -Destination $DirPrefix

    }
```

Sample tree /F before

```
└───one
    │   _7Y_one.txt
    │
    └───two
        │   _7Y_two.txt
        │
        └───three
            │   _7Y_three.txt
            │
            └───four
                    _7Y_four.txt
```

And after running the script

```
───one
   ├───two
   │   ├───three
   │   │   ├───four
   │   │   │   └───_7Y_
   │   │   │           _7Y_four.txt
   │   │   │
   │   │   └───_7Y_
   │   │           _7Y_three.txt
   │   │
   │   └───_7Y_
   │           _7Y_two.txt
   │
   └───_7Y_
           _7Y_one.txt
```

Explaining the line:

```
If(!(Test-Path "$($_.Directory)\$Prefix"))
```

- When adressing the property of an object `$_.Directory` inside a string  expression you have to enclose it in `$()` to be unambiguous/force evaluation.
- Test-Path returns $true/$false, to reverse the condition either use `-not` in the If - or - negate with `!(Test-Path ...)`

Comment: Oh man, that filter is game changing. I really had not thought to use it that way. Can I ask how the Test-path works here? I have had trouble with it in the past, where it can't validate it even if the path is correct, without specifying the path type (see my param).

Comment: See changed/appended answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and your help with formatting/logic. This solution worked in one test, but in another it failed (this was on my work machine) because when the script got to the move-item because it tries to move the files from C:\WINDOWS\system32\FILE This is a similar issue to what I had before... Is there any chance you'd know why this would be? It creates the folders like before but gives this error this for every item instead of moving them:

Comment: Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\_7Y_Oldfile.txt' because it does not exist.

At line:29 char:15
+               Move-Item $_ "$($_.Directory)\$Prefix"
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 

(C:\WINDOWS\system32\_7Y_WFX07.DOT:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: Well you are not intentionally working in the systemdir `C:\WINDOWS\system32` ? You are runnign this with different user/credentials/scheduled job? I suggest you insert a Push-Location to begin in a defined folder, eventually add the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or shorter `-EA 0` to the gci.

Comment: I do not intend to work from the systemdir, no. I am running it as myself, with administrator credentials. I have not attempted to schedule this task yet. The push location at least has it looking in the right place now, but for some reason it is only finding and moving files in the parent now, and not in any of the subdirectories. So it still creates the new folder underneath, but does not move any files in subdirectories, because it still cannot find the path.

Comment: Is the error persistent if you restart with a new powershell? I just tested again on my ramdisk without problems. The where-Object should exclude files which are already in a folder with prefix name. I slightly changed the move command.

Comment: With the slightly changed move command, it worked as expected on both machines. Thank you so much for all of your help!